# Display "Options" dialog on Export Menu

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export

When Exporting a map, the "options" dialog has disappeared. The file type is also cutoff. Any suggestions as to how to fix this? It is a work computer so I cannot easily un- and re-install.
[image: "Options" dialog not displaying]

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application of the ArcGIS Desktop product?

Comment: This is probably a similar problem to yours, have you tried this solution? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71856/arcgis-export-dialog-options-missing

Comment: I am using ArcMap.
Thanks!